# Python , Using Astype partially on the array

Tags: python, csv

Im having a problem using astype and multiplying the values by 255.
The problem is, the first column of this CSV shouldnt be changed by asType or multiplied because its a label for a class.

How can i do this conversion to 'uint8' and multipliying by 255 without changing the 0 col of the csv ?

```
  with open(trainingFolder + "standardization_traindata.csv", 'wb') as fp:
        for i in range(0, aux_data.shape[0]):
            column = aux_data[i, :].tolist()
            #
            column = np.array(column).astype('uint8') * 255
            #
            column = map(lambda x: str(x) + ',', column)
            column = ''.join(column)[0:-1]
            fp.write(column + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved by doing this :

```
with open(testingFolder + "zca_whitening_testdata.csv", 'wb') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)

    temp_list = []

    temp_list.append("label")

    for j in range(0,aux_data.shape[1]-1):
        header = "pixel"+str(j)
        temp_list.append(header)

    writer.writerow(temp_list)

    for i in range(0, aux_data.shape[0]):
        writer.writerow(aux_data[i,:].tolist())
```